# Как понять можно ли использовать библиотеку

Tags: android, лицензирование, авторские-права

Раньше как то не задумывался над таким простым вопросом,

вот есть библиотека на гите

https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad

и использую ее у себя в проете. Проект комерческий.

Впрос: можно ли ее использовать в проете?

Там стоит лицензия апаче 2, но что это значит?

Кто то знаком с этим?

Comment: Вот тут смотрели?
https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad/blob/master/LICENSE
тут описано,что можно делать, а что нельзя делать с этой библиотекой. Первым пунктом стоит коммерческое использование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочтите более-менее грамотный перевод лицензии Apache 2.0 на русский язык

[фтыкать сюда](http://www.dataved.ru/2011/03/apache-license-2.html)

> В соответствии с условиями настоящей Лицензии, каждый Участник настоящим предоставляет Вам вечную, неэксклюзивную, бесплатную, безвозмездную, безотзывную (кроме случаев, перечисленных в этом разделе) патентную лицензию производить, произвести, использовать, предлагать **продать, продавать**, импортировать и иным образом передавать Работу по всему миру.

Answer (score 1):

https://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0 это ссылка на лицензию (на Английском языке)

http://www.dataved.ru/2011/03/apache-license-2.html Это перевод лицензии.

Она довольно большая, поэтому я не решился отправить её вам текстом